# No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: spring-boot, postman, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to access my api through Postman, that returns response in ByteArrayOutputStream. But it gives error in postman as shown below.

My api,

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/excelsheet")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayOutputStream> downloadExcel() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out =departmentService.executeGridObjectListDemo();
        System.out.println(out);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=department.xlsx");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(out);

    }
```

How can I access this api through postman ?

I am getting this Error,

```
"timestamp": "2019-08-11T10:22:54.603+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:225)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "path": "/api/department/excelsheet"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions for your problem. First, you are write your stream into HttpServletResponse or you can read the file into inputStream and write inputStream into InputStreamResource and return it.

First:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/excelsheet")
    @ResponseBody
    downloadExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
         ...
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = departmentService.executeGridObjectListDemo();
         ...
         try {
                OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                out.writeTo(outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
                // second close can be put in a separate try-catch
                out.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {

         }
         ...
     }
```

Second:

```
org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on InputstreamResource -- this worked for me

```

@GetMapping(value = "/png", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> example() throws IOException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(PDFConverterUtility.testConvertToPNG());
    }

````

Answer (score 1):

Try changing out to a byte array, that worked for me:

```
return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(out.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/excelsheet")
@ResponseBody
downloadExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     ...
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = departmentService.executeGridObjectListDemo();
     ...
     try {
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            out.writeTo(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
            // second close can be put in a separate try-catch
            out.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {

     }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I realized that the above code helped me getting response in postman.But I am still getting the same error in my console.